# Boolean field in OLAP cube

Tags: ssas

What is the best practice for presenting boolean data in an OLAP cube? Should I create a boolean dimension containing two rows, true and false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and create a dimension.  It may sound strange at first, but think of the end user who ends up selecting a radio button for "male/female", or "sold/unsold", etc.